# How to get the list of items that have a particular subitem?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-table

I have table where each row starts with a "checkbox", I'd like to get all the TR that contains a checkbox and it is check.

Something like this:

```
$('#' + tableId + ' > tbody > tr:contains(td > input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (i, item) {

        alert('delete ' + $(item).data('row-id'));

    });
```

That code doesn't work, it gets stuck. Probably because the "contains" selector is only for text. How could I do it?

Regards.

Comment: Note that `tableId` must not start with a number, that might cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's [has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$('#' + tableId + ' > tbody > tr:has(td > input[type=checkbox]:checked)').each(function (i, item) {

  alert('delete ' + $(item).data('row-id'));

});
```

---

For better performance (see the jQuery API docs), use this:

```
$('#' + tableId + ' > tbody > tr')
.filter(':has(td > input:checkbox:checked)').each(function (i, item) {

  alert('delete ' + $(item).data('row-id'));

});
```

Since the `has` query cannot be run through `querySelectorAll()`, there's no need to use `[type=checkbox]`.

Comment: It get stuck as well, what could be the problem?

Comment: There is a missing closing parenthesis for the `has` as well as the `contains` in the original code.

Comment: @kingjiv: That might be it! Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `:contains` selector.

If you want it to be anywhere inside the `<tr>` (even inside nested elements)

```
$('#' + tableId + ' > tbody > tr td > input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (i, item) {
```

If you want it directly inside of it

```
$('#' + tableId + ' > tbody > tr > td > input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (i, item) {
```

Comment: Both of these will loop over the checkboxes.  He would like to loop the `tr` elements which contain the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You could just grab the checkboxes and then find their closest `tr`:

```
$('#' + tableId + ' > tbody > tr > td > input[type=checkbox]:checked').closest("tr")
```

Note, you're also missing  `)` to close the `contains`.

Comment: This piece of code will query the DOM twice, which is not the best way to go about it...